# Set color limits for matplotlib colormap

Tags: matplotlib, color-mapping

I made a function to get the hex code given to a set of data as follows:

```
from matplotlib import cm, colors
def get_color(series_data, cmap='Reds'):
    color_map = cm.get_cmap(cmap, 20)
    f = lambda x: colors.rgb2hex(color_map(x/series_data.max())[:3])
    return series_data.apply(f)
```

The `cm.get_cmap(cmap, 20)` generates a matplotlib.colors.LinearSegmentedColormap object that is ranged from the minimum value of the input `series_data` to its maximum.

I cannot see how could I define the color limits for the data to be evaluated. For instance, what if I wanted to set constant color limits, defining as the minimum the value 0 and the maximum 100? How could I do that within my function?

I tried to substitute `series_data.max()` to `100` to control the max equivalent color (max), but I couldn't control the cmin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parameter of `color_map` needs to be scaled to the [0.,1.) range. For instance, if the minimum (maximum) color value needs to be obtained for the `lo` (`hi`) value:

```py
from matplotlib import cm, colors
import pandas as pd

def get_color(series_data, cmap='Reds', lo=None, hi=None):
    if lo is None:
        lo = series_data.min()
    if hi is None:
        hi = series_data.max()
    if lo == hi:
        raise Exception('Invalid range.')
    color_map = cm.get_cmap(cmap, 20)
    f = lambda x: colors.rgb2hex(color_map((x-lo)/(hi-lo))[:3])
    return series_data.apply(f)

s = pd.Series(np.linspace(0,3,16))
colz = get_color(s, lo=1, hi=2)
for x, c in zip(s, colz):
    print('{:.2f} {}'.format(x,c))
```

The sample output is

```
0.00 #fff5f0
0.20 #fff5f0
0.40 #fff5f0
0.60 #fff5f0
0.80 #fff5f0
1.00 #fff5f0
1.20 #fdc7b0
1.40 #fc8363
1.60 #ed392b
1.80 #af1117
2.00 #67000d
2.20 #67000d
2.40 #67000d
2.60 #67000d
2.80 #67000d
3.00 #67000d
```